# OpenGL Flashing?

Tags: c++, opengl, gdi

I'm trying to draw some text in OpenGL while the program draw a cube or any Opengl native so, when I try to put the text on the screen it flashes very fast and I don't know why, I tried to change the Sleep value and nothing...

The code is below; [here is a GIF showing the problem](http://gyazo.com/2cb75802048bd54b3c8a7fd2aa1be749).

The green background is the cube, the camera is very close to the background, you can move back with the `NUM_2`.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
#include "default.h"

using namespace std;

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
DWORD WINAPI WorkLoop(LPVOID PARAMS);
void keyScan (MSG msg, Camera cam);

HDC hDC;
HGLRC hRC;
HWND hwnd;

RECT WBounds;


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    MSG msg;
    BOOL bQuit = FALSE;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_OWNDC;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = "GLSample";
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);;
    Screen ();

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
        return 0;


    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0,
                          "GLSample",
                          "OpenGL Testing",
                          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                          Scr.sx/2-630,
                          Scr.sy/2-450,
                          1260,
                          900,
                          NULL,
                          NULL,
                          hInstance,
                          NULL);

    GetClientRect(hwnd, &WBounds);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    EnableOpenGL(hwnd, &hDC, &hRC);  ///ENABLE OPENGL

    Camera cam = Camera (0, 0, -1);

    CreateThread(0, 0x1000, &WorkLoop, 0, 0, 0);

    while (!bQuit)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) bQuit = TRUE;
            else
            {
                keyScan (msg, cam);
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            renderSimulation (cam);
            SwapBuffers (hDC);
        }
        Sleep(1);
    }

    DisableOpenGL(hwnd, hDC, hRC);
    DestroyWindow(hwnd);
    return msg.wParam;
}

DWORD WINAPI WorkLoop(LPVOID PARAMS)
{
    while (true)
    {
        InvalidateRect(hwnd, &WBounds, true);
        Sleep(33);
    }
    ExitThread(0);
}


float x = 0.0f, y = 0.0f, z = 0.0f;
float rx = 0.0f, ry = 0.0f, rz = 0.0f;
char* textas = "test";

void keyScan (MSG p, Camera cam)
{
    if (p.message == WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        if (p.wParam == ARROW_RIGHT)      {x += 0.1; cam.SetCameraPosition (x, y, z);}
        else if (p.wParam == ARROW_LEFT)  {x -= 0.1; cam.SetCameraPosition (x, y, z);}
        else if (p.wParam == ARROW_UP)    {y += 0.1; cam.SetCameraPosition (x, y, z);}
        else if (p.wParam == ARROW_DOWN)  {y -= 0.1; cam.SetCameraPosition (x, y, z);}
        else if (p.wParam == NUM_8)       {z += 0.1; cam.SetCameraPosition (x, y, z);}
        else if (p.wParam == NUM_2)       {z -= 0.1; cam.SetCameraPosition (x, y, z);}
        else if (p.wParam == L)           SetFullScreen (p.hwnd, hDC, hRC);
        else if (p.wParam == K)           textas = "cambiado";
    }
}

HFONT Font = CreateFont(40, 0, 0, 0,FW_NORMAL, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, DEFAULT_CHARSET,OUT_TT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,ANTIALIASED_QUALITY, FF_MODERN, TEXT("Arial"));
HPEN BoxPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(0, 255, 0));
HPEN OutlinePen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 3, RGB(0, 0, 0));
HPEN CHPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(0, 0, 0));
HBRUSH CHBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 255, 0));

void drawtext(HDC hdc, int x, int y, const char * text)
{
    SetBkMode (hdc, TRANSPARENT);
    SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(0, 255, 0));
    SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(255, 255, 255));
    TextOutA(hdc, x, y, text, strlen(text));
}

/*void Draw(HDC hdc, int x, int y, float dist)
{
    int width = 20000 / dist;
    int height = 45000 / dist;
    SelectObject(hdc, OutlinePen);
    SelectObject(hdc, WHITE_BRUSH);
    Rectangle(hdc, x - (width / 2), y - height, x + (width / 2), y);
    SelectObject(hdc, BoxPen);
    Rectangle(hdc, x - (width / 2), y - height, x + (width / 2), y);
    SetTextAlign(hdc, TA_CENTER | TA_NOUPDATECP);
    std::stringstream ss2;
    ss2 << "Dist: " << dist << " m";
    drawtext(hdc, x, y + 90, ss2.str().c_str());
}*/

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            int win_width = WBounds.right - WBounds.left;
            int win_height = WBounds.bottom + WBounds.left;
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC Memhdc;
            HDC hdc;
            HBITMAP Membitmap;
            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            Memhdc = CreateCompatibleDC (hdc);
            Membitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap (hdc, win_width, win_height);
            SelectObject (Memhdc, Membitmap);
            //FillRect (Memhdc, &WBounds, WHITE_BRUSH);
            SelectObject (Memhdc, Font);
            SetTextAlign (Memhdc, TA_LEFT | TA_NOUPDATECP);
            drawtext(Memhdc, 100, 100, textas);

            //Draw (Memhdc, 20, 50, 90.0);

            /*SelectObject(Memhdc, CHPen);
            SelectObject(Memhdc, CHBrush);*/

            BitBlt (hdc, 0, 0, win_width, win_height, Memhdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
            DeleteObject(Membitmap);
            DeleteDC(Memhdc);
            DeleteDC(hdc);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            ValidateRect(hwnd, &WBounds);
        }
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        {
            switch (wParam)
            {
                case VK_ESCAPE:
                    PostQuitMessage(0);
            }
        }
        case WM_ERASEBKGND:
            return 1;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Two problems with your program:

1. Setting a background brush for a OpenGL window will make the OS visibly clear the window with the brush before sending WM_PAINT (upon which you overdraw with OpenGL). By using InvalidateRect you're triggering this erase-with-background before WM_PAINT
2. Double buffered OpenGL pixelformats and drawing with the GDI don't go well together. If you want to draw text you'll have to do it differently. For example drawing to a DIBSECTION DC and then drawing that bitmap per using a textured quad. Or using a font rasterizer that addresses OpenGL  (FTGL, Glyphy or the likes).